# How to pull out a number from a cell in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a CSV spreadsheet containg multiple entries in the exact form of

## randomemail@west123.com,"","41","6",

How would I be able to extract the "41" in each case as a number? Please keep in mind I start from A1, and would like my B1 to be "41", as a number...

#### randomemail2@random.com,"","21","0",

for example the above entry should be "21" in the column next to it....
etc

Also, the 41 can be a single or triple digit number
Thank you in advance

Comment: so is that example text all sitting in cell A1?

Comment: Yes, A1, A2 A3 etc. starting from A1

Comment: can it be more than a triple digit?

Comment: No. it will be in the form of 1 , 12 or 123... no more than 3 digits

Comment: @jdoethough usually letters are used for columns and numbers for rows.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in cell B1 and copy down as far as required

```
=MID(A1,FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1)+1)+2,FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1)+1)+1)-FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1)+1)-3)*1
```

a shorter version of the above which search for the occurrence of `","` in your string instead of just `,`

```
=MID(A1,FIND(""",""",A1)+3,FIND(""",""",A1,FIND(""",""",A1)+1)-FIND(""",""",A1)-3)*1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!